# Android: Adapter not updating data

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter

Here is my code:

```
public class ForecastFragment extends Fragment {
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mforecastAdapter;
    public ForecastFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu,MenuInflater inflater){
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.forecastfragment, menu);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if(id == R.id.action_refresh){


            FetchWeatherTask weatherTask= new FetchWeatherTask();
            weatherTask.execute("94043");
            return true;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        String[] forecastArray = {
                "Mon 6/23 - Sunny - 31/17",
                "Tue 6/24 - Foggy - 21/8",
                "Wed 6/25 - Cloudy - 22/17",
                "Thurs 6/26 - Rainy - 18/11",
                "Fri 6/27 - Foggy - 21/10",
                "Sat 6/28 - TRAPPED IN WEATHERSTATION - 23/18",
                "Sun 6/29 - Sunny - 20/7"
        };
        List<String> weekForecast = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(forecastArray));



        mforecastAdapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        getActivity(), // The current context (this activity)
                        R.layout.list_item_forecast, // The name of the layout ID.
                        R.id.list_item_forecast_textview, // The ID of the textview to populate.
                        weekForecast);

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);


        ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);
        listView.setAdapter(mforecastAdapter);

        return rootView;
    }

    public class FetchWeatherTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String[]> {

        private final String LOG_TAG = FetchWeatherTask.class.getSimpleName();
        //GIST

        /* The date/time conversion code is going to be moved outside the asynctask later,
         * so for convenience we're breaking it out into its own method now.
         */
        private String getReadableDateString(long time){
            // Because the API returns a unix timestamp (measured in seconds),
            // it must be converted to milliseconds in order to be converted to valid date.
            Date date = new Date(time * 1000);
            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("E, MMM d");
            return format.format(date).toString();
        }

        /**
         * Prepare the weather high/lows for presentation.
         */
        private String formatHighLows(double high, double low) {
            // For presentation, assume the user doesn't care about tenths of a degree.
            long roundedHigh = Math.round(high);
            long roundedLow = Math.round(low);

            String highLowStr = roundedHigh + "/" + roundedLow;
            return highLowStr;
        }

        /**
         * Take the String representing the complete forecast in JSON Format and
         * pull out the data we need to construct the Strings needed for the wireframes.
         *
         * Fortunately parsing is easy:  constructor takes the JSON string and converts it
         * into an Object hierarchy for us.
         */
        private String[] getWeatherDataFromJson(String forecastJsonStr, int numDays)
                throws JSONException {

            // These are the names of the JSON objects that need to be extracted.
            final String OWM_LIST = "list";
            final String OWM_WEATHER = "weather";
            final String OWM_TEMPERATURE = "temp";
            final String OWM_MAX = "max";
            final String OWM_MIN = "min";
            final String OWM_DATETIME = "dt";
            final String OWM_DESCRIPTION = "main";

            JSONObject forecastJson = new JSONObject(forecastJsonStr);
            JSONArray weatherArray = forecastJson.getJSONArray(OWM_LIST);

            String[] resultStrs = new String[numDays];
            for(int i = 0; i < weatherArray.length(); i++) {
                // For now, using the format "Day, description, hi/low"
                String day;
                String description;
                String highAndLow;

                // Get the JSON object representing the day
                JSONObject dayForecast = weatherArray.getJSONObject(i);

                // The date/time is returned as a long.  We need to convert that
                // into something human-readable, since most people won't read "1400356800" as
                // "this saturday".
                long dateTime = dayForecast.getLong(OWM_DATETIME);
                day = getReadableDateString(dateTime);

                // description is in a child array called "weather", which is 1 element long.
                JSONObject weatherObject = dayForecast.getJSONArray(OWM_WEATHER).getJSONObject(0);
                description = weatherObject.getString(OWM_DESCRIPTION);

                // Temperatures are in a child object called "temp".  Try not to name variables
                // "temp" when working with temperature.  It confuses everybody.
                JSONObject temperatureObject = dayForecast.getJSONObject(OWM_TEMPERATURE);
                double high = temperatureObject.getDouble(OWM_MAX);
                double low = temperatureObject.getDouble(OWM_MIN);

                highAndLow = formatHighLows(high, low);
                resultStrs[i] = day + " - " + description + " - " + highAndLow;
            }
                for(String s:resultStrs){
                    Log.v(LOG_TAG,"Forecast entry:" + s);
                }
            return resultStrs;
        }
        @Override
        protected String[] doInBackground(String... params) {
            // These two need to be declared outside the try/catch
            // so that they can be closed in the finally block.
            if(params.length == 0){
                return null;
            }
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;

            // Will contain the raw JSON response as a string.
            String forecastJsonStr = null;

            String format = "json";
            String units = "metric";
            int numDays = 7;

            try {
                // Construct the URL for the OpenWeatherMap query
                // Possible parameters are avaiable at OWM's forecast API page, at
                // http://openweathermap.org/API#forecast
                final String FORECAST_BASE_URL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?";
                final String QUERY_PARAM = "q";
                final String FORMAT_PARAM = "mode";
                final String DAYS_PARAM = "cnt";
                final String UNIT_PARAMS = "unit";

                Uri builtUri  = Uri.parse(FORECAST_BASE_URL).buildUpon()
                        .appendQueryParameter(QUERY_PARAM, params[0])
                        .appendQueryParameter(FORMAT_PARAM, format)
                        .appendQueryParameter(UNIT_PARAMS, units)
                        .appendQueryParameter(DAYS_PARAM,Integer.toString(numDays)).build();
                URL url = new URL(builtUri.toString());
               // Toast.makeText(getActivity(),builtUri.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Built Uri" + builtUri.toString());
                // Create the request to OpenWeatherMap, and open the connection
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.connect();

                // Read the input stream into a String
                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                if (inputStream == null) {
                    // Nothing to do.
                    return null;
                }
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    // Since it's JSON, adding a newline isn't necessary (it won't affect parsing)
                    // But it does make debugging a *lot* easier if you print out the completed
                    // buffer for debugging.
                    buffer.append(line + "\n");
                }

                if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                    // Stream was empty.  No point in parsing.
                    return null;
                }
                forecastJsonStr = buffer.toString();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error ", e);
                // If the code didn't successfully get the weather data, there's no point in attemping
                // to parse it.
                return null;
            } finally {
                if (urlConnection != null) {
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
                if (reader != null) {
                    try {
                        reader.close();
                    } catch (final IOException e) {
                        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error closing stream", e);
                    }
                }
            }
            try{
                getWeatherDataFromJson(forecastJsonStr, numDays);
            }
            catch (JSONException e){
                Log.e(LOG_TAG,e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String[] result){
            if(result!=null){
                mforecastAdapter.clear();
                for(String dayForecastStr:result){
                    mforecastAdapter.add(dayForecastStr);

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is arrayadapter is not displaying updated weather data. It gathers the updated data and shows them in logs but doest not update the adapter.
In my debugging Ive found that in onPostExecute(String[] result) is the string[] result is empty. Can any expert explain why?

Answer (score 0):

OnPostExecute receives the returned value of doInBackground, while you're always returning null. What did you expect?

Comment: @user2807723 if this is correct select it as a correct answer instead of answering yourself...

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. doInBackground wasnt returning anything. So I added a return call. Fixed.